# How to read the build ID of NextJS?

Tags: javascript, git, next.js

With NextJS, it's possible to create a build ID, according to the docs : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/generateBuildId

It's also possible to get it according to the last git version : https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-build-id

But the question is : how do I read this build ID? I'd like to display it inside the window console.

Comment: @phd Because I also want to read the git commit/version SHA.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested it, but I think you can try the old (I guess it's deprecated now, but it still should work) way of passing `env` vars through the `env` key in the config, like that:

```
const nextBuildId = require('next-build-id')

const buildId = nextBuildId({ dir: __dirname })

const nextConfig = {
  generateBuildId: () => buildId 
  env: {
    BUILD_ID_ENV: buildId
  },
};
```

And it will be available later as `process.env.BUILD_ID_ENV`

To use it in the client side component potentially you would have to name it as `NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILD_ID_ENV`, not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

this works in server component because that package uses `fs`

```
import buildId from "next-build-id";

console.log("next-build-id", await buildId());
```

proof of work:

[image]

Comment: That's clever too, and you can then pass it as a prop to a client component if you want to log it in the console or something. But then to use in for example in production environment the deployment should contain `.git` folder too, no? That might be a downside.

Comment: @Danila for some reason it is not working in `next.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

From @Danila i got solution like this

```
const nextBuildId = require('next-build-id')

const nextConfig = {
  env: {
     NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILD_ID: nextBuildId.sync({
      dir: __dirname,
      describe: true
    })
  },
};
```

also working at client side by calling process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILD_ID

note: it wont work 'describe: true' wont work on vercel because .git not exist.